# How do I adjust oven time to cook 2 dishes at the same time

Tags: cooking-time

I have seen a chart for cooking two dishes that list different temperatures at the same temperature, just changing the length of time for one dish. Can anyone provide a chart like this, or at least explain how to pick a common temperature and adjust cooking times? What kinds of dishes will this work for?

Comment: +1 It's obviously a bit more complex than just a simple chart, but I think this question is well worth trying to answer.

Comment: This question is *not* a duplicate of the link @Jefromi provides in my opinion because the other question only addresses increasing quantity of the same ingredient which would nominally bake that the same temperature anyway.  This question specifically indicates different temperatures, which implies differing items.  Still, this question is very vague and hard to address since the two items could be *anything*.

Comment: The question as it stands - 'does anyone have this chart' - is not really much good surely?

Comment: Before voting to close as not a real question or not constructive, please consider editing the question instead. The OP's intent is pretty obvious, and there's an answerable question here.

Comment: Can you bake meringues and pizza together in the same oven?   There are limits.  We need the OP to give us some hint or scope of what he or she wants to achieve in order to help edit the question, or to have a coherent answer.  I added a new answer the older question, which may provide some insight, but certainly isn't a direct answer to this question.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ No, we don't really need any hints from the OP to answer this. The limits are part of the answer; that's why I edited that last sentence in. It's quite possible to provide generalities.  No one is going to downvote an answer and say "but what about meringues, or croissants, or baguettes, or ...?" The main point of a question like this is less-sensitive things, anyway - a couple things with plenty of liquid that ask for temperatures 25-50F apart and bake for a while.

Comment: I think that the key part of the question is the *different temperatures* aspect.  Yes, there are going to be dishes that are sensitive to temperatures, but there should be some general guidelines for holiday baking when you've got lots of things that all are supposed to cook at different temps.